# Sending app requests from server side

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a facebook app where users create invitations and invite their friends to join the event. It has 3 steps and second step has a custom friend selector where I let user select some of his friends that he/she would like to invite. In step 3 after confirming I would like to send notification/message/request to invitees and I can't figure out a nice way to do that.

I can't use JS friend request as I have a custom friend selector.
I couldn't find a way to send a message from server side.
I was able to send app request but only to app users.

Is there A way of sending a little notification to user that he was invited to an event by his friend?

*Not all invitees are app users
*Not all users accepted TOS
*Don't want to post to wall until invitee accepts or rejects the invitation

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Hope this helps someone. Here is how I was able to send a server side request.

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new('app_id', 'access_token')
@oauth_token = @oauth.get_app_access_token
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@oauth_token)
graph.put_object("fb_id", "apprequests", {:message=>'Welcome to my app'})
```

Comment: I am using Koala a ruby gem to interact with Facebook. I was able to send app request. App requests are not so obvious and there is a high chance that users might not notice the request. Is there a way to send notification or message to app users and not app users?

Answer (score 0):

To finally answer this question (according to the latest API Version v2.5): It is not possible to send notifications or App requests server side to users who did not authorize your App. You should use the official apprequest dialog, or other dialogs like the send dialog. Or just send emails.